# Looping to make uppercase characters for a vector<struct> element

Tags: c++, vector, loops

Upon debugging I had thought I did it right. But it was only the first member as the first element in the vector that was corrected.

```
while ( !inFile->eof() )
{
    getline( *inFile, str1, ',' );      
    sStruct.str1 = str1;
    getline( *inFile, str2, ',' );
    sStruct.str2 = str2;
    getline( *inFile, str3, ',' );
    sStruct.str3 = atof( str3.c_str() );
    getline( *inFile, str4 );
    sStruct.str4 = atof( str4.c_str() );

    myLength = sStruct.str1.length();

    for( ; sIndex < myLength; sIndex++ )
    { 
        if ( 97 <= str4[sIndex] && str4[sIndex] <= 122 )
        {
            str4[sIndex] -= 32;
        }
    }   

    sStruct.str1 = str1;
    vectorData->push_back( sStruct );
}
```

Implementing this code under the method that I chose to read the file in, only changes the first struct member, in this case, str1, to all uppercase characters. All characters remain unaffected for the same structure member, str1.

What is my loop not doing?

Comment: Why does your code change str4 but not store it anywhere?

Comment: should sIndex be initialized or is it global?

Answer (score 3):

As already stated in the comments there are a few things you should look at in your code first:

- what is the value of sIndex, before you enter this while-loop?
- why are you working with str4[] in the for-loop but get the length and do assigns on str1?
- are you really sure, that only str1 is changed to uppercase? the given code doesn't do that...
- don't do the uppercase-calculation yourself but use the [toupper()](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/clibrary/cctype/toupper.html) method instead

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest using transform from the header algorithm to convert, it's cleaner:

```
transform( str4.begin(), str4.end(), str4.begin(), toupper );
```